# What's the best Rails gem to create a database dashboard with graph and radio buttons like these photos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graph, model, radio-button, dashboard

What's the best Rails gem to create a database dashboard with graph and radio buttons like these photos, knowing that I'm still newbie in Ruby On Rails.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [administrate](https://github.com/thoughtbot/administrate) repo is well maintained, have a look at it.
If you need more, a dashboard is mostly CSS, abit of JS and HTML. Grab the [AdminLTE](http://adminlte.io/) template and work with that. It should cover most of your needs. There are afew of it that should get you on the ground running.

Happy hunting